# Suppressing all cout from a project

Tags: c++, objective-c, debugging, cout

There is a trick on Objective C that you can use to suppress all NSLogs you have used on your project from the final release.

The trick is adding this to the `.pch` file:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define NSLog(...) /* suppress NSLog when in release mode */
#endif
```

is there a similar trick to suppress all cout?

I have couts like this:

```
cout << "number: " << source->count() << endl;
```

or

```
cout << "file error";
```

etc., that are used under debugging but I would like to strip from final release. I don't want cout to print anything on the final release.

Is there a way to do that from the `.pch` file or something globally like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433302/null-stream-do-i-have-to-include-ostream) seems to do something like that. If `NullStream()` supplies your null stream, there you go.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Or flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: In the future, if you find yourself saying "Hey, look at this other question, it has the entire answer," please just flag to close the question as a duplicate of the other.